# Axis2 + Rampart: Specifying password digest in policy header

Tags: web-services, authentication, apache-axis, digest, rampart

I am trying to send username and a password over web services using axis2 and rampart. I want to send the password as a **digest**, but for some reason the password is only sent in cleartext. According to several sources, it should happen when I add the   to both services.xml and axis2.xml, but it doesnt seem to work. I have also tried to add Digest under the  sub-header. Relevant sections of services.xml (server side) and axis2.xml (client side) is given below. Can anybody see anything wrong?

My axis2.xml

```
<wsp:Policy wsu:Id="UTOverTransport"
    xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd"
    xmlns:wsp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy">
    <wsp:ExactlyOne>
        <wsp:All>
            <sp:SignedSupportingTokens
                xmlns:sp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy">
                <wsp:Policy>
                    <sp:UsernameToken
                        sp:IncludeToken="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy/IncludeToken/AlwaysToRecipient">
                        <wsp:Policy>
                            <sp:HashPassword />
                        </wsp:Policy>
                    </sp:UsernameToken>
                </wsp:Policy>
            </sp:SignedSupportingTokens>
            <ramp:RampartConfig xmlns:ramp="http://ws.apache.org/rampart/policy">
                <ramp:user>test</ramp:user>
                <ramp:passwordCallbackClass>sec.PWCBHandler</ramp:passwordCallbackClass>
            </ramp:RampartConfig>
        </wsp:All>
    </wsp:ExactlyOne>

</wsp:Policy>
```

My services.xml

```
<wsp:Policy wsu:Id="UTOverTransport"
    xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd"
    xmlns:wsp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy">
    <wsp:ExactlyOne>
        <wsp:All>
            <sp:SignedSupportingTokens
                xmlns:sp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy">
                <wsp:Policy>
                    <sp:UsernameToken
                        sp:IncludeToken="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy/IncludeToken/AlwaysToRecipient">
                        <wsp:Policy>
                            <sp:HashPassword />
                        </wsp:Policy>
                    </sp:UsernameToken>
                </wsp:Policy>
            </sp:SignedSupportingTokens>
            <ramp:RampartConfig xmlns:ramp="http://ws.apache.org/rampart/policy">
                <ramp:passwordCallbackClass>sec.PWCBHandler</ramp:passwordCallbackClass>
            </ramp:RampartConfig>

        </wsp:All>
    </wsp:ExactlyOne>
</wsp:Policy>
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem with you configuration is that namespaces that you use suggest Axis to interpret it as WSS 1.1 configuration. As far as I can tell from Axis sources, it does not support hashing passwords from username token. Probably it is a feature available from WSS 1.2.

You need to define supporting token using WSS 1.2 namespaces:

```
  <sp:SignedSupportingTokens xmlns:sp="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-securitypolicy/200702">
    <wsp:Policy>
      <sp:UsernameToken sp:IncludeToken="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-securitypolicy/200702/IncludeToken/AlwaysToRecipient">
        <wsp:Policy>
             <sp:HashPassword />
        </wsp:Policy>
      </sp:UsernameToken>
    </wsp:Policy>
  </sp:SignedSupportingTokens>
```

That will hash the password with nonce and created by default.

Answer (score 1):

I found you may need to add something like this:

```
<wsp:Policy wsu:Id="UsernameToken" xmlns:wsu=
  "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd"
  xmlns:wsp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy">
 <wsp:ExactlyOne>
  <wsp:All>
   <sp:TransportBinding xmlns:sp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy">
     <wsp:Policy>
      <sp:TransportToken>
        <wsp:Policy>
         <sp:HttpsToken RequireClientCertificate="false"/>
        </wsp:Policy>
      </sp:TransportToken>
     </wsp:Policy>
   </sp:TransportBinding>
   <sp:SupportingTokens
     xmlns:sp="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-securitypolicy/200702">
    <wsp:Policy>
     <sp:UsernameToken sp:IncludeToken="http://docs.oasis-open.org/
          ws-sx/ws-securitypolicy/200702/IncludeToken/AlwaysToRecipient"/>
    </wsp:Policy>
   </sp:SupportingTokens>
  </wsp:All>
 </wsp:ExactlyOne>
</wsp:Policy>
```

Ref: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jws4/index.html

Comment: That doesn't enforce digest passwords, that enforces you to use a HTTPS transport when using the Username Token.